# SignalR on Azure: Web or Worker Role?

Tags: azure, signalr, azure-cloud-services

I need to deploy my SignalR back-end application on Azure, without any dependency to ASP.NET (I use a console app for testing purposes).

So, I need an Azure **Cloud Service**, and I don't know if I should go for a worker role or a web role. According to [this link](http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/host-owin-in-an-azure-worker-role), I successfully created a worker role hosting my SignalR app, but I want to know if this is the best way to go.

Comment: SignalR is just another library like Web API, it doesn't affect whether you should use Web, Worker Role or Web Apps. What do you want to use SignalR for? Sending notifications to browsers or other servers?

Comment: Thanks. I want to send messages to web and mobile clients (both are JavaScript apps)

Comment: In this case you should be looking at push notifications, not SignalR. Mobile clients are *guaranteed* to get disconnected from one second to the next.

Comment: It's more like a real time dialog client/server so I think SignalR is the best

Comment: I would consider using web apps since it should be the simplest to deploy, scale, and maintain compared to web or worker roles. A tutorial on deploying SignalR is here: http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/deployment/using-signalr-with-azure-web-sites